# Is there something like "Integer non-linear programming" without mixed-integers

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I just wanted to know whether problems exist that belong to the category "Integer non-linear programming" without belonging to the category "Mixed-integer non-linear programming"? While having ecoutered several "Integer linear programming" problems I have yet to see an "Integer non-linear programming" prblem as all the ones that I have seen are from the type "Mixed-Integer non-linear programming". Also here in this overview )and in several others) this category is not mentioned "[enter link description here](https://neos-guide.org/content/optimization-taxonomy). Do such kind of problems exist and if so can anyone imagine why it is mentioned so rarely.

My assumption would be that in fact such types of problem exist but maybe the do not occur that offten. But I am not an expert. This is why I want to ask you. I'd appreciate your input. Thanks in advance

Comment: Binary quadratic optimization probably fits that class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this was not what I basically wanted to know. Binary quadratic optimization is something more special where you have a quadratic optimization problem. I wanted to know whether generally there are "Interger non-linear programming" problems.